# What is the best way to resize image in Swift using controls?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I need to resize image using slider, that way that while the sliders value is being changed the image shrinks or becomes larger accordingly.
Is there any way to optimize this and not redraw image each time the value changes?

Comment: Does the pixel size of the image has to become larger or smaller, or just how it's displayed? Please provide a bit more information, e.g. is the image displayed inside an UIImageView?

Comment: @JosefZoller No the pixel size does not have to change, only it's appearance on the screen. Yes, it is displayed in UIImageView

Comment: Then you could simply resize the UIImageView or his constraints according to the slider value.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `scale` up/down when the `slider` value changes as below,

```
let sliderValue: CGFloat = 0.5
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: sliderValue, y: sliderValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use transform

```
@IBAction func zoomSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
yourImgView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: sender.value, y: sender.value)
}
```

set the value between 0.1 to 2 in slider and test it.Accordingly change the values you want.

to get original size

```
yourImgView = CGAffineTransform.identity
```